# Help me get this search query right

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

My users table has a `first_name` and `last_name` column and `name` is a virtual attribute. For example I have these records:

```
Aen Tan
Lily Chou Chou
Nuon Baby
```

When I search with two words I get the expected result:

```
"aen tan" Aen Tan
"lily chou" Lily Chou Chou
```

But when I search with one word e.g. **"aen"** I get all three records.

Here's my query:

```
scope :find_by_name, lambda {|name| where("first_name LIKE ? or last_name LIKE ?",  '%' + name.split(' ').first + '%', '%' + name.split(' ')[1, name.split(' ').length-1].join(' ') + '%')}
```

And it produces this SQL when I search with one word **"aen"**:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (first_name LIKE '%aen%' or last_name LIKE '%%')
```

I think the problem is with the last name being empty. What's a good fix for this? If only one word is given should I search both columns with the word?

This brings me to something else I'm thinking. If I search for "tan+aen" I will get nothing but it's absolutely possible users will get the order of names reversed. How can I buuild a query which takes this into consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a scope as a function something like this. This makes the assumption that a name is only going to be 2 words.

```
def self.find_by_name(name)
  names = split(' ')
  if names.size == 1
    YourModel.where("first_name LIKE ?", "%#{names.first}%")
  else
    YourModel.where("first_name LIKE ? AND last_name LIKE ?", "%#{names.first}%")
  end
end
```

A better fix would be to have a full_name table attribute that you could search on. This would be easy to build in an after create on your model.

Then you scope would just be:

```
scope :find_by_name, {|name| where("full_name LIKE ?", "%#{name}%")}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can :

- NOT search in `last_name` if there isn't a second word in the query search
- Put your condition in a `AND` condition instead of an `OR`. I guess you would search for users with *both* the first name *AND* the last name matching your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE (first_name LIKE '%Aen%' And last_name LIKE '%%')
```

I think this is the solution. I tried and and it gives the same result you want....Hope that helps